# TFRecord dataset from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to create a dataset of 7 bands from tfrecord files that I downloaded from google earth engine, am I doing this correctly:# Define the feature columns for parsing the TFRecord data. I am using this for Machine Learning and while it works, the perfoamce is terrible. So I want to know if I am reading the data correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Specify the path to the CSV file containing the labels
label_csv_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Measures/TFRLabel12010Complete.csv'

# Load the label CSV dataset
label_df = pd.read_csv(label_csv_path, header=None, names=['filename', 'label'])
label_dict = dict(zip(label_df['filename'], label_df['label']))

# Specify the path to the folder containing the TFRecord files
folder_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/AgebRGB20107_BandsTFR40_40Patches'

# Get the list of file paths in the folder
file_paths = [os.path.join(folder_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(folder_path) if filename.endswith('.tfrecord')]


# Filter the file paths list based on the filenames in the label CSV
file_paths_matched = [file_path for file_path in file_paths if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0] in label_dict]

# Define the feature columns for parsing the TFRecord data
bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']
patch_dimensions_flat = [40, 40]
image_columns = [
  tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=patch_dimensions_flat, dtype=tf.float32) 
  for k in bands
]

image_columns += [tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=patch_dimensions_flat, dtype=tf.int64)]

# Create a dictionary mapping feature names to feature columns
image_features_dict = dict(zip(bands, image_columns))

# Define a parsing function to parse a single example from a TFRecord
def parse_image(example_proto):
    try:
        parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_features_dict)
        # Reshape the input tensor to 4D
        image = tf.reshape(parsed_features['B1'], (patch_dimensions_flat[0], patch_dimensions_flat[1], 1))
        for band in bands[1:]:
            image = tf.concat([image, tf.reshape(parsed_features[band], (patch_dimensions_flat[0], patch_dimensions_flat[1], 1))], axis=-1)
        # Normalize the image
        image = (image - tf.reduce_min(image)) / (tf.reduce_max(image) - tf.reduce_min(image))

        # Apply data augmentation to the image
        image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
        image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
        image = tf.image.rot90(image, k=tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)) # randomly rotate the image by 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees
        image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=tf.float32)

        return image
    except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
        print(f"Error parsing example: {e}")
        return None


# Create a dataset that reads only the matched TFRecord files
image_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_paths_matched)

# Min-max scale the labels
labels = [label_dict.get(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0], -1) for file_path in file_paths_matched]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_labels = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(labels).reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()

# Create the labels dataset from the scaled labels
labels_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(scaled_labels)

# Combine the image and labels datasets
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_dataset.map(parse_image), labels_dataset)).filter(lambda x, y: y != -1)
```